# What is the prototype chain for a function constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

I have been learning about the prototype chain from a tutorial and am confused by the prototype chain for a function constructor.

Here is my constructor function with a prototype and a new instance:

```
let Fun2 = function(name) {
    this.name = name
}

Fun2.prototype.who = () => console.log('who')

const name = new Fun2('bill')
```

then as I expect, the `__proto__` property of the `name` instance is the `Fun2` prototype, however the prototype property of `Fun2` points to the `Object` prototype:

```
name.__proto__.__proto__
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
```

I also learned that a functions prototype chain goes up to a general `function.prototype` (the same as an array has an array.prototype), since `Fun2` is a function, why doesn't it point to the `function.prototype` and then point to the `Object.prototype`, I don't understand why it is skipping this step, can someone clarify this please.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work/42880438#42880438) will help?

Comment: I took a look but found it hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that can be confusing is that the `prototype` property (of a constructor) gives the prototype for objects that the function will *construct*, while the `__proto__` property of the constructor refers to the prototype used for creating the constructor. These are unrelated prototypes: the constructor has a prototype chain that has nothing to do with the prototype chain of an object that is constructed with that constructor.

> why doesn't it point to the function.prototype and then point to the Object.prototype

It **does** that. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype)` is `Object.prototype`.

Look at these results:

```js
const Fun2 = function(name) {}
const name = new Fun2('bill');

console.log(
    "Test prototype chain of the constructed object:",
    Object.getPrototypeOf(name) === Fun2.prototype, // true
//                                       ↓
              Object.getPrototypeOf(Fun2.prototype) === Object.prototype, // true
);

console.log(
    "Test prototype chain of the constructor:",
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Fun2) === Function.prototype, // true
//                                       ↓
              Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype, // true
);
```

See also [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/5459839) and, if you wish, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880438/5459839) in that collection of answers.

Comment: I'm confused by this line `Object.getPrototypeOf(Fun2.prototype) === Object.prototype` why is this not pointing to Function.prototype. I did have a look at your other answer but sorry I couldn't follow it all. Shouldn't everything related to `Fun2` be pointing to the `Function.prototype`

Comment: That is exactly the misunderstanding. There are two prototype chains involved here, not just one. The object that the constructor creates is not a function, while the constructor itself is a function. So we clearly have two different types of objects, each with their own prototype. As long as you think they should be on the same prototype chain you'll miss the point. Note again that the `prototype` property says nothing about the constructor itself, but about the objects that are created by it... which are not functions.

Comment: So does this sound correct, because `Fun2.prototype` is an object rather than a function it has a different prototype chain which goes up to the `Object.prototype`. Whereas `Fun2` on it's own is a function and it goes to the `Function.prototype`? so in theory if I added another object and function inside the `Fun2` function then they would also both have separate prototype chains? one for Object and one for Function?

Comment: Yes, although it is irrelevant that the other function is *inside* `Fun2`. Functions (like `Fun2`) are themselves objects, and they have `Function.prototype` as prototype -- that is unrelated of *where* they are defined. Non-function objects generally don't have `Function.prototype` as prototype.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
function myFunction() {}

myFunction.prototype.Test = function () {};

console.log(myFunction.__proto__ === Function.prototype); //True

console.log(myFunction.constructor === Function.prototype.constructor); //True

console.log(myFunction.prototype.constructor === myFunction); //True
```

In case if you are creating the object using the `new` operator

```
let obj1 = new myFunction();

console.log(obj1.__proto__ === myFunction.prototype); //True

let obj2 = Object.create(myFunction.prototype);

console.log(obj2.__proto__ === myFunction.prototype); //True
```